# Count worked days per employee

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, worksheet-function

I am creating a spreadsheet in Google Sheets for a client who wants the sheet to pull data from their Google Calendar to calculate how many days each employee works.  They use Calendar for their scheduling.

So I know that I need the formula to look through the calendar for the specific employee name, and then count how many days they work in a 3-month period.  Hours worked aren't counted, just days.

**Edit**
I need to have Sheets pull info from Calendar:
[image: Calendar]
To fill in these fields:
[image: Spreadsheet]
The client would like the spreadsheet to just stay up to date, but if that's not possible, then I would put a link or button in B1.
I'm thinking that I'll need formulae in A, B, C and D to the effect of `=FIND("drname"` `=FIND("officeabbreviation"`, yadda yadda yadda.  But I don't know the specifics of the yadda yadda yadda. I do have a table that I can MATCH INDEX for the Dr's names and Office abbreviations.

**Edit 2**
I do need to know how to import the Calendar to Sheets, as well as the formulas.

Comment: it is possible but it really depends on how data looks like to choose the best approach. can you share a copy/dummy of your sheet?

Comment: I'd use QUERY instead of MATCH INDEX.  I had an Excel moment there.

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you export all names under 1 column you can use simple **`QUERY`** to get what you want:

```
=QUERY({A1:A}, "select Col1, count(Col1) 
                where Col1 is not null 
                group by Col1
                label count(Col1)'Total days'", 1)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: @user0, Thank you, but I'm not understanding how this connects to Calendar.  How does it know which Calendar to pull from?  For instance, in my Google acct., I have several Calendars.

Comment: @user0, That's the part I need to know.  I'll edit the question to provide more info.  Thank you! :)

Comment: @Keiva well, then pls do edit your question again and remove any traces of google sheets formulas, as this is question of how to export google calendar into google sheets not how to deal with formulas